# Highchart xAxis label steps wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am loading Highcharts like this.

```
var options = {
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart_box',
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        crosshairs: true,
        labels: {
            step: 5,
            rotation: -45
        }
    },
    series: []
};
```

Then I have a function which is called when graph needs to be loaded. Upon calling the function, data is fetched through AJAX and assigned to series and date lie this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url/charts',
    type: 'post',
    data: data
}).done(function(data) {
    var dateCount = data.dates.length;
    var stepCount = 1;

    if (dateCount > 10) {
        stepCount = 5;
    }

    options.xAxis.categories = data.dates;

    $.each(data.series, function(name, elem) {
        options.series.push({
            name: name.replace('_', ' ').toUpperCase().trim(),
            data: elem
        })
    });
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

The issue here is that even though I have given `step` as 5 , it is showing dates with 15 dates interval. I mean in xAxis labels. It seems like it will be multiplied by three always. If I give 2, it will show 6 days interval in labels. Everything working fine in a chart which is not using AJAX to load data.

Comment: add dummy data for check

Comment: Instead of step, have you tried to set [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) on xAxis ?

Comment: To expand on Sebastian's comment - the tickInterval tells the chart how far apart to create tick marks on the axis.  The step property tells the chart to skip some of the labels for those tickmarks.  So the chart is determining to put a tick mark every 3 units, and you are telling it to skip the labels in increments of 5 - so your labels are now 15 units apart.